# C++ When to handle an exception

Tags: c++, exception

If you have function calls like this, which level is the best to handle my throw ? I just want to pop up an error message.

```
  class Test {
     void A() {
        B();
        // try and catch here ?
     }

     void B() {
        C();
        // try and catch here ?
     }

     void C() {
        throw 1;
     }
  }

  int main()
  {
     Test test;
     test.A();
     // try and catch here ?

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: This really depends on the actual situation.  You might want to catch some exceptions while letting other propagate up the call stack.

Comment: IMHO as long as you're aware that an exception can be thrown, is the important thing.  Where or if you catch it, that is subjective.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie _subjective_ doesn't fully fit here IMHO, _use case dependent_  should be the better description. I'm not that sure, if this makes the question off-topic, because of going  _too broad_, or needing more clarification.

Comment: Yes, poor wording.  Should be on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you decide to handle an exception greatly depends on the design pattern and the specific scenario but in general you want to handle exceptions as soon as you can reliably deal with.

You should resort to throwing an exception higher on the call stack if you have insufficient information to handle the exception. some reasons are as follows:

1. exceptions are more expensive than checking return types for error handling
2. if you keep throwing exceptions up the call stack a lot of code will not run (or at least you have to write a lot of messy finally blocks)
3. functions high up on the call stack will be burdened with catching many different types of exceptions and it gets in the way of their intended job

conversely, if you catch and deal with an exception as early as you can reliably  do so:

1. functions that are higher on the call stack than the catch block will not even know exception happened
2. you will get performance boost by avoiding excessive exception throwing
3. generally better design for seperation of concerns.

Comment: _"you will get performance boost by avoiding excessive exception throwing"_ It's the `catch` introducing the cost, not the `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on your actual use case.

If you just want to pop-up an error message and terminate your program you shouldn't catch anything at all.

The default [std::terminate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) handler would do this already.

If you just want to show an error message, and proceed with construction, you should catch from the level where you are able to overcome the errors and can safely continue your programs operational state.